# Learn guitarpro

Tags: theory, sheet-music, software

Can anyone suggest a good source from where I can learn guitarpro software? Books, youtube videos, etc. I have looked through youtube and google but there are a lot of bits and pieces but nothing well put together.
Thanks in advance and Cheers!!

Comment: Why does no-one think to start with the [product manual](https://support.guitar-pro.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002399509-GP7-5-Guitar-Pro-7-5-User-s-guide-) any more?

Comment: @Tetsujin - if all else fails - read the instructions...

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you do it… this applies to **any** new software

You get the [product manual](https://support.guitar-pro.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002399509-GP7-5-Guitar-Pro-7-5-User-s-guide-) - which is an authoritative information source, unlike YouTube, which is just some random guesser who's already tried to make sense of it, thinks he's an expert & is passing on second hand information with pretty pictures, because he's heard that this is the modern way to gain fame & make money. This is not the way to learn anything.

Once you have the manual, you read it, cover to cover.
Most of it won't make any sense at all as it's far too complicated & you haven't even used the software yet.

Then you start to use the software.

If you struggle you try to find reference in the manual - which you may or may not find yet because of lack of familiarity with the whole setup.

Then, after two weeks of this… you read the manual again.
This time you'll already have a grounding in what the software does, so you will reinforce existing knowledge & pick up new useful information.

You then go back to using the software again.

Guess what?
After another month or two of this… **you read the manual again.**

This is how you gain a deep understanding of complex software.

Answer (score 0):

[Here you go! GP7 Manual and Enjoy](https://support.guitar-pro.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002399509?utm_source=GP7Software&utm_medium=HelpGP7&utm_campaign=HelpGP7Menu&from=GP7Software)

Comment: Is there any other source apart from user manual?

Comment: The manual is already great. The UI is easy if you even know basics of guitar tablatures. I recommend try experimenting with what you make and suppose you have problem simply search online and don't waste time in understanding every features after all it isn't any software for bombing planet Earth.XD